# How to return main thread from runBlocking without changing the return type

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, suspend

I have a main func that needs to return some value while I have a suspend func that just need to trigger in the background while the main function is being called

```
fun mainFunc(): List<Int> {

if (noInteger)

   return emptyList

val myList = doMainActivity()

runBlocking{

launch {

 doHeavyWork()


}


}

 
return myList


}

suspend func doHeavyActivity(){

delay(5000L)

}
```

Now using this it is running sequentially which will not serve my purpose. I want my main to return before Heavy work completes.

I tried

```
runBlocking{

launch {

 doHeavyWork()


}

return@Runblocking myList
}
```

while it asks me to change return Type of the main function. If I change that I cannot return the emptyList and have to change all the calling function not sure how other function who calls mainFunc() will work with the return@Runblocking

Comment: This is intended behavior to not accidentally leak background tasks. You can't workaround it using `return`. If you need to launch a task which runs independently to your current code, then you need to use some scope. Depending on your case it could be a predefined scope like `lifecycleScope` in Android, it could be a scope created with `CoroutineScope()`, or even the `GlobalScope`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen here? Do you want to wait for `doHeavyWork()` to complete before `main()` returns?

Comment: @Joffrey Well, OP was very clear about this :-) "I want my main to return before Heavy work completes.".

Comment: @broot oh thanks, I had missed that sentence

Comment: @broot, I think your first comment is a sufficient and complete answer you could post.

Answer (score 0):

Coroutines were designed around the concept of [structured concurrency](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#structured-concurrency) which basically means that concurrent operations are structured as a tree of tasks. Bigger tasks consist of and owns their subtasks.

By default, when we start a new coroutine using `launch()` or `async()`, it automatically becomes a part of our current task. We can't finish the current task before all our subtasks finish. Failure of one of subtasks affects the parent. Cancelling the parent automatically cancels subtasks. And so on.

This is exactly why `runBlocking()` waits for `doHeavyWork()`. It doesn't matter you used `launch()` - this heavy task is still a subtask of `runBlocking()`, so `runBlocking()` can't finish before the heavy task. You can't workaround this using `return@runBlocking` neither.

And this behavior is intentional. Otherwise you could easily leak this heavy background work. What if that background task would crash and you would wait for its results? What if it would hang in the middle of processing? What if you don't need this background work anymore? All these problems are much easier to solve if we assume the background task is not a "fire and forget" unit of work, but actually, it is a part of a bigger task.

Of course, sometimes we really need to schedule a tasks which is not a part of our current execution context. We would like it to run entirely asynchronously to the caller. For this case coroutines introduced scopes, which are like separate trees of tasks. Using scopes you can launch a task in another tree than yourself.

Depending on your case you may like to use one of predefined scopes, for example in Android we have scopes like `lifecycleScope` or `viewModelScope` which are related to the lifecycle of different Android components. You can create your own scope using [CoroutineScope()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/), but in his case you should handle the lifecycle of this scope manually, according to the documentation. Alternatively, you can use [GlobalScope](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/) which provides a truly fire and forget behavior, but it is discouraged exactly for this reason.

If you decide on the scope you want to use, you then don't need to use `runBlocking()`, but you launch directly using the scope:

```kotlin
val myList = doMainActivity()

scope.launch {
    doHeavyWork()
}

return myList
```